# Javascript regex to parse human readable dates

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I have a dates in String in Javascript that could look like:

```
1h
1h2m
1d3m4s
2d2h2m2s2ms
1ms
3s5ms
```

The indicators will not change, they are `d, h, m, s, ms`

What would be a good regex to parse the numbers out:
for `3s5ms`, it should be:

```
parsed = [0,0,0,3,5]
```

for `1d4m`, it should be:

```
parsed = [1,0,4,0,0]
```

Comment: If you've tried anything, add attempts in question.

Comment: Why not using formatting of durations from Momentjs? http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
var getNumbers = function (string) {
    var numbersArray = string.match(/(?:(\d+)d)?(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m)?(?:(\d+)s)?(?:(\d+)ms)?/);
    numbersArray.shift();
    return numbersArray.map(function (val) {
        return parseInt(val) || 0;
    })
};


getNumbers("3s5ms") // [0, 0, 0, 3, 5]
getNumbers("2d2h2m2s2ms") //[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```